# SQL convert rows to columns with static headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a data set that I need to transform from rows to columns.

I looked at pivot and does not really answer the problem since I need specific static column headers (not matching the data names).

Here is how the current data is stored:

```
Id | SpCode    
------------------------- 
1    AA  
1    BB    
1    CC    
2    FF    
2    LL    
3    TT    
3    YY    
3    ZZ    
3    XX    
4    AA    
4    BB        
5    AA    
6    WW    
6    MM    
6    PP
```

I need to display it like this.

I will never have more than 5 columns and would like to keep the column name static so I can join and refer to it easily.

```
ID  SpCode1 |SpCode2 | SpCode3 | SpCode4 | SpCode5
1   AA      |BB      | CC       
2   FF      |LL         
3   TT      |YY      |ZZ       |XX  
4   AA      |BB                 
5   AA              
6   WW      |MM      |PP
```

Much appreciated for any help.

PS: using SQL Server 2014

Thanks

Oren

Comment: Google "pivot sql server" or "conditional aggregation sql server". Literally all you need to do is assign each row a number (partitioned by id) and pivot it...

Comment: Like this, for reference: `SELECT ID, [1] [SpCode1], [2] [SpCode2], [3] [SpCode3], [4] [SpCode4], [5] [SpCode5] FROM (SELECT ID, SpCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN FROM myTable) T PIVOT (MAX(SpCode) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `pivot`.  Another is conditional aggregation.  I find the latter easier to use:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then spcode end) as spcode_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then spcode end) as spcode_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then spcode end) as spcode_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then spcode end) as spcode_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then spcode end) as spcode_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by spcode) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Gordon. Thanks a bunch.